# Send and Receive TCP data each 16ms interval

Tags: android

I need to send and receive data(data transmission) each 16ms , time should be 16ms not more and not less
which method you propose for that?
please let me know if you want to implement this app
a method with no memory leakage and a method that app don't stop working
thank alot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a Timer with a Timer Task like below :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do your work here
    }
 }, 16);
```

Comment: I tried It, but after a while (about 10 mins) app gives me the STOP WORKING error!
Is there any way to get rid of ?

Comment: since I'm new to android ,don't know how to have it!!

Comment: open the logcat from bottom bar in android studio and you can see error